# Python initialization

Tags: python, class, init

I have this code:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c, d...):
   self.a = a
   self.b = b
   etc
```

I'm thinking of replacing it with:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c, d...):
   args=locals()
   for key in args:
     self.__dict__[key] = args[key]
```

Is this a bad idea?  Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Might want to be careful about the self argument, but otherwise looks OK

Comment: Will the number of inputs change, or is there a set number?

Comment: Thanks Ixop,

The number of input will not change.

Comment: Can you explain what you hope to accomplish with this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @ThiefMaster's comment about `**kwargs`:

If you are taking in 20 arguments, it might make more sense to require your users to send arguments via keyword instead of position: with 20 arguments, there is a decent chance that someone using your code will get the arguments in the wrong order.

Consider *only* accepting kwargs while having a predefined list of keys you want to accept and raising a ValueError if you don't receive them. So you could use `**kwargs` and then check that everything is there.  E.g.

```
INITIAL_ARGS = set(['a','b','c','d','e'...])

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    if not INITIAL_ARGS.issubset(set(kwargs.iterkeys())):
        raise ValueError("Class <myclass> requires 20 keyword arguments"
                          "only given %d" % len(kwargs))
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Not sure whether this is more or less Pythonic than your original, but it seems like it would save a ton of time later on when trying to figure out why someone using your code might be getting strange errors.

Comment: If the OP expects the same number of args in every call (that was said in a comment), I'd go with `==` rather than `issubset` - don't want the user to add other random keyword arguments that don't do anything but pollute the namespace!

Answer (score 9):

From the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): **Simple is better than complex.** and **Readability counts.**

The explicit assignments are much more readable and simpler than using magic to set the values.

Comment: The thing is there are approximately 20 such variables; is explicit assignment still better?

and by explicit assignment, you mean "self.a = a", etc?

Comment: A method accepting 20 variables sounds bad. HAve you considered accepting `**kwargs` and doing `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`?

Answer (score 1):

Always consider readability over clever design. Is the replacement code easier to read? I would probably just leave it. Remember that simple is better than complex. As the ThiefMaster said, the explicit assignments are more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for Python3 users: the `init` decorator from [drastic](https://github.com/clemtoy/drastic/blob/master/README.md).

```
@init
def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h):
    # nothing to write here!
```