# Pythonic way of inheriting many classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

In an effort to code in a more python and OOP-style way, I wonder if anyone could advise me on implementing this concept please.

Let's say I have a base class for fruit, say apple and banana, which contains basic properties for the class, e.g. color. Then I want to class which inherits from fruit called juice, which adds methods and properties, e.g. volume, sugar.

A rough structure might be:

```
class Fruit(object):
def __init__(self, fruit_name):
    if fruit_name == 'apple': 
        self.color = 'green'
        self.sugar_content = 2
    elif fruit_name == 'banana':
        self.color = 'yellow'
        self.sugar_content = 3
```

Then I inherit the methods of my Fruit classes:

```
class Juice(Fruit):
    def __init___(self, fruit_name, volume, additives):
        PERHAPS I NEED TO USE A SUPER STATEMENT HERE TO PASS THE fruit_name parameter (which is 'apple' or 'banana' BACK TO THE FRUIT CLASS? I want this class to be able to access sugar_content and color of the the fruit class.
        self.volume = volume
        self.additives = additives

    def calories(self, sugar_added):
        return sugar_added + 2*self.sugar_content* self.volume # i.e. some arbitrary function using the class parameters of both this juice class and the original fruit class
```

So ultimately, I can create an object like:

```
my_juice = Juice(fruit_name='apple', volume=200, additives='sugar,salt')
print 'My juice contains %f calories' % self.calories(sugar_added=5)
print 'The color of my juice, based on the fruit color is %s' % self.color
```

ALTERNATIVELY, I wonder if it is better NOT to inherit at all and simply call the fruit class from a Juice class. e.g.

```
class Juice(object):
    def __init__(self, fruit_name, volume, additives):
        self.fruit = Fruit(fruit_name=fruit_name)
        self.volume = volume # ASIDE: is there an easier way to inherit all parameters from a init call and make them into class variables of the same name and accessible by self.variable_name calls?
        self.additives = additives

    def calories(self, sugar_added):
        return sugar_added + 2*self.fruit.sugar_content* self.volume
```

In some ways, this above feels more natural as self.Fruit.sugar_content directly indicates the sugar_content is a property of the fruit. Whereas if I inherited, then I'd use self.sugar_content, which is a property of the fruit although could be confused with the sugar content of the juice class which is dependent on other factors.

OR, would it better still to have a separate class for each fruit, and put the logic statement to evaluate the fruit_name string passed to the Juice class witin the Juice class **init** and then use e.g.:

```
class Apple(object):
   self.color = 'green'

class Banana(object):
    self.color = 'yellow'

class Juice(object):
    def __init__(self, fruit_name, other params):
         if fruit_name == 'apple':
             self.Fruit = Apple
             self.sugar_content=2
         elif fruit_name == 'banana':
             self.Fruit = Banana
             self.sugar_content=3
         # Or some easier way to simply say
             self.Fruit = the class which has the same name as the string parameter fruit_name
```

I appreciate all of the above would work in theory, although I'm looking for suggestions to develop an efficient coding style. In practice, I want to apply this to a more complex project not involving fruit, although the example encompasses many of the issues I'm facing.

All suggestions / tips / suggest reading links welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Juice is not a Fruit, so it's not wise to set up your class structure that way.

Comment: Re: your `#ASIDE`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973764/python-initialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your first option is closest to a good idea, but here's an improvement:

```
class Fruit:

    def __init__(self, name, sugar_content):
        self.name = name
        self.sugar_content = sugar_content
```

Now the logic for determining how much sugar each `Fruit` contains is moved outside the class definition entirely. Where can it go? One option would be to sub-class:

```
class Apple(Fruit):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("apple", 2)
```

Alternatively, if the only differences between the `Fruit`s are name and sugar content, just create instances and feed in the data (e.g. from a file):

```
apple = Fruit("apple", 2)
```

Now how about the `Juice`. This is *composed of* `Fruit`, but isn't itself actually `Fruit`, so inheritance isn't a good fit. Try:

```
class Juice:

    def __init__(self, fruits):
        self.fruits = fruits

    @property
    def sugar_content(self):
        return sum(fruit.sugar_content for fruit in self.fruits)
```

You can pass an iterable of `Fruit` instances to make a `Juice`:

```
>>> mixed_fruit = Juice([Fruit("apple", 2), Fruit("banana", 3)])
>>> mixed_fruit.sugar_content
5
```

You can then extend this to encompass ideas like:

- How much of each `Fruit` goes into the `Juice`;
- What the volume of the `Juice` is (another `@property` calculated from the ingredients?); and
- What additives (water, sugar, etc.) are present.

It would be sensible to work in consistent proportional units, e.g. `sugar_content` in grams of sugar per gram of `Fruit` (i.e. percentage).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to think about this is with three entities `Fruit`, `Juice`, and `Juicer`. The `Juicer` is responsible for taking a certain `Fruit` and creating a `Juice` of the corresponding type `Orange => OrangeJuice`. Then you could have two hierarchies of classes with `Orange` inheriting from `Fruit` and `OrangeJuice` inheriting from `Juice` with `Juicer` essentially mapping between them.

This gets you around a lot of tricky problems that your proposed solution would generate. For instance, if I had a class called `Slicer` that consumed some `Fruit` produced a `FruitSalad`(`Fruit[] => FruitSalad`). In your proposed abstraction I could give `Slicer` an `OrangeJuice` instance (which you propose as a type of `Fruit`) and expect it to spit out a delicious `FruitSalad` but instead all I get is a soggy counter top.

Comment: I think `juicer` and `slicer` should probably be functions, rather than classes, (or methods of a `FoodProcessor`!) but I like the idea!

Comment: I think I proposed these as a subversive attempt to show how a functional language with a type system would approach this type of problem. So `Juicer` and `Slicer` are really just `A=>B` morphisms mapping between the type sets. You can def get away with making these functions in `Python`. But nothing stops you from applying the OOP model strictly and getting the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually Juice should not inherit from Fruit but for the sake of your question let's suppose it makes sense to do that. In your first code sample you **must** call

```
super(Juice,self).__init__(fruit,name)
```

In Python 3 that would be

```
super().__init__(fruit,name)
```

Now to your second question. Composition **is** the way yo go here. Juice is composed by Fruits but it is not his place to create them

```
class Juice(object):
    def __init__(self, fruit, volume, additives):
        self.fruit = fruit
        self.volume = volume
        self.additives = additives
```

This way you can:

```
apple = Apple(...)
apple_juice= Juice(apple,2,None)
```

And I think that answers your third question too.